# Using a single RecyclerView.Adapter for multiple RecyclerViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**What I've done:** I have a viewpager with 4 fragments which inflate the same layout containing a RecyclerView. I've built a single Adapter for all of the fragments. When I click an item it loads data and appends the data to a List and set the new data to the adapter.

**Problem:** the problem is when I change the data of particular recyclerview of a particular fragment the changes take effect on all the recyclerviews.

Comment: I think we need some code to help you.

Comment: *the problem is when i change the data of particular recyclerview of a particular fragment. the changes take effect on all the recyclerviews.* - what exactly did you expect to happen when those views share the **same** adapter?

Comment: @Luksprog i just wanted to know if there is a way to use a same adapter for all recyclerviews

Comment: @Lukesprog the answer is yes, just use a different data source

Comment: @Lukesprog i do use different resources and it does render out as it should but when i swipe to different pages the Viewholder messes it up/

Comment: @Luksprog or i should go with multiple adapters for multiple recyclerViews  .

Comment: It may work with the same adapter and different data sources but the question is why would you want to do that(what would be the benefit)? You should always use a dedicated adapter instance for views that support adapters(ListViews, RecyclerViews etc).

Comment: @Luksprog i am using a dedicated adapter instance for it

Comment: @Luksprog i wanted to do it because, i want to minimize the code, i don't want to duplicate stuff for the same thing. because the data source is similar for all the recyclerviews with defferent values

Comment: @Prakhar hi there, did u find any way how to do it.? i am also stuck on it and to make slight changes even more if there are just different number of elements of same View type in RV still we need to create separate adapters :/ for the fragments..!