# Android: issue of using two instances of the same Fragment in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-recyclerview

I have a ViewPager that has two pages, each page contains an instance of the same Fragment. In each fragment, I have an instance of the same RecyclerView. The problem is that, on the item click event of the first RecyclerView.Adapter, it get the data from the second RecyclerView. The ViewHolder of the RecyclerView.Adapter is:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView timestamp;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        timestamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);

        // Setup the click listener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Triggers click upwards to the adapter on click
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onItemClick(itemView, getLayoutPosition());
            }
        });
    }
```

And in the Fragment:

```
listAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new FeedListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {
        //feedItems.get(position) always returns the item of the second RecyclerView
       //feedItems is datasource of the adapter
    }
});
```

Fragment Code:

```
public class FeedListFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = FeedListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<Feed> feedItems = new ArrayList<Feed>();

    public FeedListFragment(){
        super();
    }

    private String getFeedUrl() {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return bundle.getString("feedUrl");
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_list,container,false);
        listView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity(), feedItems);
        listAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new FeedListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FeedDetailActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putLong("feedId", feedItems.get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                intent.putExtra("feed", feedItems.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        (new Handler()).postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        refreshContent();
                    }
                },
                1000
        );

        return v;
    }

    public void refreshContent(){
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getFeedUrl(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(final JSONObject response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    //Need to process response with an AsyncTask or progressbar will be frozen.
                    // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978274/volley-progressdialog-stuck-freeze-at-the-time-of-get-huge-amount-of-data
                    new AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, List<Feed>>() {
                        @Override
                        protected List<Feed> doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
                            ServerResponseStatus responseStatus = JSONUtil.parseServerResponseStatus(params[0]);
                            if (AppController.STATUS_OK.equals(responseStatus.getStatus())) {
                                return parseJsonFeed(params[0]);
                            } else {
                                switchState(State.ERROR, responseStatus.getErrorMessage());
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(List<Feed> feeds) {
                            if (feeds == null) {
                                return;
                            }
                            feedItems.clear();
                            feedItems.addAll(feeds);
                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            switchState(State.READY, null);
                        }

                    }.execute(response);

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //show error message
            }
        });

        // Adding request to volley request queue
        jsonReq.setShouldCache(false);

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private List<Feed> parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        List<Feed> feeds = null;
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feeds");
            feeds = JSONUtil.parseFeedList(feedArray, new JSONUtil.JSONParseOptions());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            switchState(State.ERROR, e.toString());
            return null;
        }
        return feeds;
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence titles[]; // This will Store the titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int numbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created
    private FeedListFragment homeTab;
    private FeedListFragment favTab;


    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.titles = mTitles;
        this.numbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getHomeTab();
            case 1:
                return getFavTab();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numbOfTabs;
    }

    public FeedListFragment getHomeTab() {
        if (homeTab == null) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("feedUrl", "...");
            homeTab = new FeedListFragment();
            homeTab.setArguments(bundle);
        }
        return homeTab;
    }

    public FeedListFragment getFavTab() {
        if (favTab == null) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("feedUrl", "...");
            favTab = new FeedListFragment();
            favTab.setArguments(bundle);
        }
        return favTab;
    }

}
```

It is strange, since all variables in the Adapter are non-static. Did anyone experience this issue and can help?
Thanks!!!

Comment: please post the full Fragment Code.

Comment: I've updated the question to add Fragment code and ViewPagerAdapter code

Comment: It seems that my problem is similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472702/using-a-single-recyclerview-adapter-for-multiple-recyclerviews

Comment: @ItzikSamara any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, it is a bug in my code. The onClickListener variable in the adapter was declared as static. Changed it to non static and it works.